# returned ResponseEntity "null" when stubbing OpenFeign client call

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have this test class ( for contract testing ):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServiceApplication.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0, stubs = "classpath*:/META-INF/**/mappings/**/*.json")
@ActiveProfiles({"local", "mock"})
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class ContractBase {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DocSolIngestionInterface docSolIngestionInterface;

    @MockBean
    private DocSolRequest docSolRequest;

    @Before
    public void test() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(this.mvc);

        Mockito.when(docSolIngestionInterface.postDocSolRequest(docSolRequest))
                .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().header("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8").body(createDocSolResponseMock()));
    }
```

The method call I'm having trouble with is in this method in my REST controller:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<DocSolResponse> postAssessment(@RequestBody final Assessment body) {

DocSolRequest docSolRequest = mapDocSolRequest.buildDocSolRequestModel(body);

HERE---> ResponseEntity<DocSolResponse> docSolResponse docSolIngestionInterface.postDocSolRequest(docSolRequest); 

return docSolResponse;
}
```

`docSolIngestionInterface` is a simple OpenFeign client.

When I try to stub this with the above method in my test class: `Mockito.when(docSolIngestionInterface.postDocSolRequest(docSolRequest))
                    .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok().header("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8").body(createDocSolResponseMock()));` it returns `null`.  However when I print it to console within my test method it prints the entire body perfectly as I'd expect it.

`createDocSolResponseMock()` is a local method in my test class which simply builds my POJO.  These objects are `serializable`.

I have no idea why when I try to stub this `docSolRequest` it is always `null`.

Comment: You haven't mocked MapDocSolRequest in your test.

Comment: Doesn't matter if i do or not, still doesn't work.   `ResponseEntity<>` remains null.